# How work with paths to static files with Zuul and Spring Boot

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, netflix-zuul, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix

I have a Dashboard in my service, and I'm using Spring-boot, Zuul, Thymeleaf and Eureka. My problem is that when I start to navegate into my domain, the static files get lost.

Example: I'm using the default configuration of spring boot so, all my static files are in resource/static. And I have a base template on thymeleaf that contains:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{style.css}">
```

And a Controler with:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/admin")
public class List {
  @RequestMapping("/list")
  public String list(Model model) {
    return "list";
  }
}
```

This page works well, but in the next controller (above) I get a error 404 for all css, js and image files.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/store")
public class List {
  @RequestMapping("/category/new")
  public String new(Model model) {
    return "category/new";
  }
}
```

This only happen when I pass through Zuul or Eureka.